# Defining a Constructor In an Interface Java?

Tags: java, interface

I have multiple different implementations of an object, which implement this custom `interface` I made called `Board`.

`Board` contains a method that looks like the following

```
public void ConvertFromString(String formattedString);
```

Each object implementing `Board` calls `ConvertFromString()` in its constructor.

Looks like the following.

```
public void BoardImpl1 implements Board
{
    public Board(string B)
    {
        ConvertFromString(b);
    }

    public void ConvertFromString(String formattedString)
    {
        //do some parsing on string and set up the BoardImpl properties
    }
}
```

ConvertFromString being public causes a warning, so the best practice workaround would be to make `BoardImpl` final. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Voting to close, as I think this question is better suited on StackOverflow. While your code is technically working, in practice it is not. You are not really asking for a code review, you are asking for a solution to a problem; which belongs on SO.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if my OP wasn't clear. I stated that I can make my class Final, which gets rid of the warning.

I was wondering if something should be restructured so that I don't end up making a bunch of final classes each time I want to implement the Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you get, is because you call an overridable method from your constructor. This is bad because subclasses may change the implementation of the method to access other parts of the object, while it is not fully initialized yet.

So to get rid of the warning : don't call overridable methods from the constructor.

Then how to get around your predicament?

Well you could :

- make the public method final.
- make the class final (which you found yourself)
- duplicate the logic (while possible, not the way to go)
- have the public method delegate to a private method, and have the constructor call the private method.

Like this :

```
public class BoardImpl implements Board {
    public BoardImpl(String b) {
        doConvertFromString(b);
    }

    public void convertFromString(String formattedString) {
        doConvertFromString(formattedString);
    }

    private void doConvertFromString(String formattedString) {
        //do some parsing on string and set up the BoardImpl properties
    }
}
```

I wouldn't worry about making all implementations final. *final is your friend*.